# Not sure how to respond to a colleague at work

Tags: communication, colleagues, work-environment

I joined a new work place and there had been an event where all people in other departments too got together. After the lunch two girls from my department were at the place where they were distributing the lunch packets (they were responsible for the distribution together with another guy, say Jack from another department). As I were new I didn't have many duties, so at that time I went to the place where they were. There wasn't much space to sit close to the girls, so I sat next to Jack, and kept myself occupied in my phone, while they chatted and continued their work. After some time, they wanted to clean the place, and then I also got up and helped with the cleaning. I felt that Jack and others got bit surprised that I helped voluntarily, as I was a new comer and as they didn't even ask for help. Anyway, afterwards I went home and didn't think much about it.

One part of my name is quit similar to that of Jack, say Jackqline. On another day, again we were together and there were few other guys too, one was a senior (say Mr. Pete). I knew Mr. Pete even before I came to this particular place, so he is quite chatty with me usually. So on this day, he suddenly said, "Oh, Jack and Jackqline, you both quite look similar. Both are very similar". something like that and one of the other guys said, "Oh, Jackline, Jack had been looking for you at the party!!" (there was a party a few days ago to which I didn't attend because my father was out of town). All this while Jack was also there, listening quietly to what they were saying. I didn't get what they were saying exactly at the moment, and so I thought they were probably joking about the similarity of our names (mine and Jack's) so I didn't say anything and went away together with other girls after a while.

And next, on another day where we were together, Mr. Pete quite appreciated my appearance but that day I felt as if something peculiar is there, as if he is laughing too. And around the same time, Jack went behind Mr. Pete, smiling widely. Then I began to feel as if Jack might be interested in me, and that's why they are acting odd like this. I don't know whether I'm right though.

I think Jack is a good guy. And if he proves to be so when associating too I don't have much objection to him. But at the same time I'm bit concerned about whether it'll create problems if he is not, as we both are at the same work place. And also I don't know "how to respond" if he tries to approach me to talk. Do I directly talk to him? Will others laugh then?

And how to respond if others get together and give more public comments as mentioned above? (Like, Jack had been looking for you...). On that day I didn't say anything but it might look awkward if I continue to do so, isn't it?

Perhaps Jack is impressed about me because I was helpful on the very first day we met too as mentioned above and got interested?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Maybe, this question fits the site "Interpersonal Skills - Stack Exchange" better. Here is the link:  https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would personally avoid characterising behaviour as "queer" as there are connotations attached to that word.

Comment: I read through this multiple times and still haven't understood what happened. Jack, Jackqline, Pete, two other colleagues... this is way too convoluted and confusing. You should consider rephrasing an summarizing what you wrote.

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion would be to keep yourself professional at work.

Dating with colleagues is never a good idea. This makes the workplace really challenging, and invites unintended consequences.

Comment: It’s fine when “dating” eventually changes into something permanent. And when problems in the workplace ( one person having to move jobs) is an acceptable price for the relationship. A two month fling is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

> And if he proves to be so when associating too I don't have much objection to him

Don't date at work if there is any way to avoid it. In many cases it creates a lot of problems and rarely ends well.

> And how to respond if others get together and give more public comments as mentioned above?

Going forward document every incidence of teasing: time, date, who , what was said, who else was there. Then try the approaches below. Only move to the next level if the previous didn't work.

**Level 1:** Initially ignore them and don't react. Put on your professional face, don't laugh, don't smile, don't chit-chat, and only talk about work stuff. With any luck, they will get the message and/or the teasing get boring.

**Level 2:** If this doesn't help. Have a friendly private chat. "Hey, I know you mean well, but I feel that your teasing is a bit inappropriate for the work place and it makes me a little uncomfortable. I appreciate if you could stop it"

**Level 3:** Call them out loud hard and in public right when it happens. "You are teasing me which is inappropriate and makes me uncomfortable. Stop it" Make sure you do it in front of other people.

**Level 4:** Engage HR only after everything else has failed. Research rules and policies for your company and local labor laws. That's where your paper trail comes in really handy. Make sure you don't have some vague complaints but that you can show a well documented pattern of behavior.

Comment: I met my wife at work, if I remember correctly many people do. It is tricky, but if you don't want to die alone, it is worth it.

Comment: Many people in the UK date people they meet through work. I have done it twice and the first time, ultimately I had to leave that workplace. If the thought of that risk is too much don't do it. But I wouldn't change what I did

Answer (score -3):

#### Report the "jokes" to HR if they're unwelcome.

If coworkers are making jokes about you being in a sexual relationship with a particular coworker, and those jokes are unwelcome, then it's sexual harassment. Report them to HR, and let HR deal with them. HR is not your friend, since they exist to protect the company, not the workers, but your coworkers sexually harassing you like this is opening the company to lawsuits down the line.

Comment: What about talking to those guys before involving HR? What is **sexual** harassment about that?

Comment: Engaging HR will likely backfire in this case.